# Dynamically set object attribute with map and setattr function

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Trying to achieve the following in Python 2.7.8

```
class X:
    pass

a = X()
b = X()
t={1: {1: a, 2: b}}

map(lambda x: setattr(x, 'test', 'wow'), t[1].values())
```

that gives: [None, None], while I expect it to set property 'test' on each to 'wow'
if I call **setattr(a, 'test', 'wow')** outside of map() then everything works

Comment: It _does_ set the `test` attribute to "wow". What exactly isn't working?

Comment: What's the point of using `map`? Why not just use a normal for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look at the bottom of my answer for a better way to do this.  Here is the explanation of what's going on in your example (but again, there is a better way).

```
class X:
    pass

a = X()
b = X()
t={1: {1: a, 2: b}}

map(lambda x: setattr(x, 'test', 'wow'), t[1].values())

a.test   
> wow
```

It behaves as expected.  Just that `setattr` returns `None` (all functions that don't explicitly return a value actually return `None`).  So when you `map` it, it returns `None` both times, and `map` returns the list of the things that `setattr` returned: `[None, None]`.  `map` has the side effect that it does change the attributes, which is what you're trying to do, but this isn't what `map` returns.  To demonstrate the behavior more clearly:

```
response = setattr(a, 'test', 'wow2')
print response  
> None
print a.test  
> wow2
```

Why not do:

```
for x in t[1].values():
    setattr(x, 'test', 'wow')
```

instead.  It's not at all clear why you need `map`.  Your confusion came from the fact that `map` returns a list, but what you were trying to do wasn't get the list, but rather do some operation on each object in a list.

Comment: this does not in python 3, you need to wrap the map with list()